# tablespace differentiation for oracle apex upgrade

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Lately I have been doing a lot of research on the Oracle APEX installation and upgrade process and have looked through many best practices. One thing that is still not clear to me is the differentiation of the tablespaces that must be specified during an installation:

- tablespace_apex
- tablespace_files

In the Oracle documentation, the SYSAUX is usesd in both cases, which I have bypassed with best practice experience and the initial installation of APEX (22.1) in my PDB has its own tablespace APEXSYSTEM.

`@apexins.sql APEXSYSTEM APEXSYSTEM TEMPTS /i/` 
When upgrading to a new version Oracle recommends creating a new tablespace. I can understand the reasons with the metadata separation and the easier deletion of an old version. So I created a new tablespace APEXTS23 and installed the new APEX (23.1) version.

`@apexins.sql APEXTS23 APEXTS23 TEMPTS /i/`

When installing a new version, i realized only the new schema APEX23xxxx uses the new tablespace. All other users (for example FLOWS_FILES, APEX_PUBLIC_USER, etc.) remain with default tablespace APEXSYSTEM.

Does ist makes sense for a clean upgrade routine to create a separate FILESTS tablespace once, which always grows with the time and to create a separate tablespace (e.g. APEXTS2302) only for the new APEX version.

When executing the installation script, only the tablespace_apex would then change for future use. Is this a viable approach for a standardized installation and upgrade routine?

`@apexins.sql APEXTS<XY> FILESTS TEMPTS /i/`

Comment: I don't know, I'm just a developer. As far as I can tell, *most* people - who visit Apex questions here - are also developers. Wait for a while, someone might answer your question. Meanwhile, see whether posting it on OTN Apex forum (https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/domain/dev-community/category/apex) makes sense. I'd say so, as Apex developers visit it as well and might assist.

Comment: I'm under the impression that an upgrade will only create new objects in the actual apex schema (APEX_230200). The others should only have objects that either are version independent (FLOWS_FILES has only a single table in our databases) or have no objects at all (APEX_PUBLIC_USER doesn't have any objects at all - it is just a user that APEX connects has and it has a number of roles and grants). I wouldn't bother with those 2 tablespaces.